# Can Spring have Java EE dependencies and JPA mappings?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Is this even possible? Are JPA mappings from Java EE and from Spring possible to co-exists?
We have Java EE projects and we want to rewrite everything into one Spring application. Is this possible to have Spring app with dependencies from Java EE? I know this looks like a bad idea, but we want to start rewriting old applications in small steps.

Comment: JPA is not bound to Java EE standard so it can be used from Java EE or Spring.

Comment: Best way is to try it out. Be careful on the import statements if you use same named annotations from spring or from JEE.

Comment: It is possible- in example, `javax.servlet` and `javax.jms` are part of the EE spec and are supported by Spring (they are also used outside Spring of course). Though maybe some EE apis are not as well supported as the main ones?